# Simplify JavaScript map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

Is there a way that I can simplify this code?

I was thinking if there is a way to set `{ ...filterItem, type: 'chip' }` as the parameter in map function instead of creating a const that will be returned in each state.

Is this type of syntax possible to do? If so, is there a specific term for it?

```
filtersToUse = filtersToChip.map((filterItem) => {
    const filterItem2 = { ...filterItem, type: 'chip' }

    if (filterItem.id === '12345') {
      return { ...filterItem2, labelOverride: 'new-label' }
    } else if (filterItem.id === '67890') {
      return { ...filterItem2, labelOverride: 'new-label' }
    }

    return filterItem2
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to:

1. Add `type: 'chip'` too all the elements
2. Add `labelOverride: 'new-label'` if `id` is `12345` OR `67890`

You could do something like:

```
filtersToUse = filtersToChip.map((filterItem) => ({ 
    ...filterItem, 
    type: 'chip',
    ...([ '12345', '67890'].includes(filterItem.id) ? { labelOverride: 'new-label' } : {}) 
});
```

Where we use [object spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to add the desired options, if needed

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do this:

```
filtersToUse = filtersToChip.map((filterItem) => ({
  ...filterItem,
  type: 'chip',
  labelOverride: ['12345', '67890'].includes(filterItem.id)
    ? 'new-label'
    : undefined,
}));
```

Comment: May be acceptable though `labelOverride: undefined` is not strictly the same as the absence of `labelOverride`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It depends on what the OP wants but I believe it fulfills 99% of the needs and is way more understandable/short than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is what you're searching for but i would optimize like that.

```
const newLabelItemIds = ['12345', '67890'];

const filtersToUse = filtersToChip.map((filterItem) => {
    const label = newLabelItemIds.include(filterItem.id) ? { label: 'new-label' } : {};

    return {
        ...filterItem,
        ...label,
        type: 'chip',
    };
});
```